# Explicit scheme for heat equation with Neumann boundary conditions in Maple

Tags: finite-difference, maple

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\alpha(x,t)\cdot \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+b(x,t)$

$u(x,0)=f(x)$ Initial condition

$u_x(0,t)=0$ 2nd type Boundary condition

$u_x(1,t)=0$ 2nd type Boundary condition

There is my code in Maple for the 1st type B.C. And I really do not know, what I should change in this  code to have a solution for my problem with 2nd type B.C.
What should I change in the loop ***#Boundary cond*** ?
Where do I have to use central finite differences for boundary conditions? 
What will be changed in the explicit scheme (for 2nd type B.C.)?
My code for explicit method for 1D heat equation with 1st type B.C. is below:
[image: code]

I will be very grateful, if someone helps me.

Comment: The image with your code does not show up.  Also, you can use Latex to make your problem clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that your equation probably do not have a unique solution in 2nd type B.C. because if $u$ is a solution then $u+C$ is also a solution for your equation where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Numerically, the 2nd type B.C. usually be approximated by Euler's method. For instance, in your problem, you can set $u_{N}^m=u_{N+1}^m$ where $m$ is time step and $N+1$ is partition point at boundary of $x$. You can modify your code my this method.